# how to implement abstract class and subclasses to parse json with changing structure with jackson annotations

Tags: android, annotations, jackson, restlet

I asked:

[when geting objects from a Json with restlet how can I get different objects in case the Json chnges its structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050654/when-geting-objects-from-a-json-with-restlet-how-can-i-get-different-objects-in)

So I am implementing an abstract class with 2 sub classes as suggested in:

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24051219/2394901)

I Followed the documentation in jackson annotations: [jackson-annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations) and [Annotation Type JsonTypeInfo](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonTypeInfo.html)

But I don't know how to: // Include Java class name ("com.myempl.ImplClass") as JSON property "class"

on the abstract class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.CLASS, include=As.PROPERTY, property="class")
```

I get errors:

1. Id cannot be resolved to a variable
2. As cannot be resolved to a variable

And in the subclasses:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NAME, include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({com.smartenit.client.business.rest.CapabilityWhenReadingAllDevices.class,
    com.smartenit.client.business.rest.CapabilityWhenRequestingAttribute.class})
```

I get errors:

1. Id cannot be resolved to a variable
2. As cannot be resolved to a variable
3. The value for annotation attribute JsonSubTypes.value must be some @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes.Type annotation

Answer (score 0):

I think the Jackson API has evolved.
I've tried with the sample annotations (located on the abstract class) with restlet 2.2 (leveraging jackson 2.2):

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(value = Impl1.class, name = "impl1"),
        @Type(value = Impl2.class, name = "impl2") })
```

Could you give it a try?